# 2 identical codes, get error at one

Tags: c++, char, cin

I added comments to the code, do I have a compiler issues? I can't figure it out, I tried looking on google and the book but I cant figure out why the first half of code only accepts the input with space between the number and unit and second code accepts the number and unit together.

I'm using code blocks. So far I tried closing it and opening it again.

```
int main(){

    constexpr double dollar_to_euro = 0.91;
    constexpr double dollar_to_yen = 117.07;
    constexpr double dollar_to_pounds = 0.70;
    double sum = 1;

    char curr = '\0'; // tried replacing '\0' with '0' and ' ' 

    cout << "Please enter sum, followed by currency for conversion.\n"
         << "U for dollar, E for euro, Y for yen and P for pounds.\n";

    cin >> sum >> curr; // This is my issue, it does not want to accept "sumcurr" together, it only accepts it if theres space in between 
                        // yet on the second code for inches or centimeters it does accept them being together. Look down.
                        // For example entering "5 E" works, yet "5E" does not work. 
    if(curr=='E')
        cout << "The amount " << sum << " euro is " << sum/dollar_to_euro << " dollars\n";

    else
        cout << "GOD DAMMIT !!!!\n";


    constexpr double cm_per_inch = 2.54;

    double len = 1;

    char unit = '\0';
    cout << "Please enter length followed by unit.\n";

    cin >> len >> unit; // Over here it works, this is an example from a book. Entering "5i" works. 

    if(unit=='i')
        cout << len << " in == " << cm_per_inch*len << "cm.\n";
    else
        cout << "Wrong input !\n";
}
```

Comment: Does entering "5E" for the unit work?

Comment: See the parts regarding the optional "e" or "E": http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: 5E does not work, only 5 E works. But the second code 5i works. To me they are identical, I cant understand why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Eureka !!! I got it now, thanks a lot ! I was trying to figure it out for a while now.

Comment: a more type-safe way is to define proper classes for dollars, euros and pounds, and user-define your own literals `_U`, `_E` and `_P`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `E`/`e` is valid in a floating point number but `5E`/`5e` is not a valid floating point number as you need a value after the `E`/`e`.  So when you enter `5e` the input for `sum` fails because of the invalid syntax where `5e0` would work.  If you use anything other than `E`/`e` then it will work like your second example.

For more information on the format of floating point numbers see: [Cppreference floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)